# Import Maya 3D to Papervision 3D

Tags: flash-cs5, papervision3d, maya

I have created a 3D model on Maya and i would like to export it to Papervision3D in order to use it in Adobe Flash Professional CS5. I couldn't find anything that can help me on that can you please help me how to export it.

Also i found some code how to exports 3D collada from other softwares to papervision3D but i didn't really understand how it works.

Thank You

Comment: A better fit for [Super User](http://superuser.com/), I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, you need a plugin for maya called [Collada](https://collada.org/mediawiki/index.php/COLLADA_-_Digital_Asset_and_FX_Exchange_Schema). You load that plugin, export the model in a *.dae format, then add a path to it inside Flash/PV3D.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have been created my model using separate nurbs. Did i need to convert the nurbs group it or something?

Comment: I can't quite remember how exactly I did it, but I think that the Collada plugin requires you to convert NURBS to Poly and then export to a .dae file. What i'm saying is PV3D needs a poly model but I don't know if Collada converts it into a poly-mesh so try doing it yourself.

Comment: Can i ask if i can't find any online resourses to help me with the coding in order to import it to papervision3D. I already change it to *.dae format and i want to import tis to papervision3D.

Comment: [Here](http://www.swinburne.edu.au/design/tutorials/P-maya/T-How-to-export-a-Collada-file-and-import-it-into-Papervision-3D/ID-168/)  you have a video tutorial and if you scroll to the end of [this page](http://www.swinburne.edu.au/design/tutorials/maya-video-tutorials.php) you will see 4 video tutorials that describe the whole process